# Get Files With Multiple Extensions And Adding Them To Listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, file-extension

I'm trying to understand why I can't return multiple file extensions with `.GetFiles`.

Here's is my current code, which works fine.

```
        'Returns only the filenames based on the directory that is selected
        Dim fi = From f In New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).GetFiles("*.txt").Cast(Of IO.FileInfo)() _
                    Order By f.CreationTime
                    Select f

        For Each fileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo In fi
            ListBoxFileAvailable.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name)
        Next
```

When I run this, my listbox is only populated with *.txt files.

Here is the code if I add `("*.txt, *.xlsx")` and run the code again, nothing is populated in my listbox.

```
        'Returns only the filenames based on the directory that is selected
        Dim fi = From f In New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).GetFiles("*.txt, *.xlsx").Cast(Of IO.FileInfo)() _
                    Order By f.CreationTime
                    Select f

        For Each fileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo In fi
            ListBoxFileAvailable.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name)
        Next
```

How can I go about adding multiple file extensions in my listbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, works pretty well. I added the **Where f.Extension = ".txt" OrElse f.Extension = ".xlsx"**

```
        'Returns only the filenames based on the directory that is selected
        Dim fi = From f In New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).GetFiles().Cast(Of IO.FileInfo)() _
                  Where f.Extension = ".txt" OrElse f.Extension = ".xlsx"
                  Order By f.Name
                  Select f

        For Each fileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo In fi
            ListBoxFileAvailable.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name)
        Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are looking for a file that looks like this: `somefile.txt, *.xlxs` which isn't possible because you can't have a `*` in a windows filename. Instead, build a list of all the files for each extension

```vb
    Dim extList() As String = {"*.txt", "*.xlxs"} ' I think you actually want .xlsx but whatever...
    Dim fileList As New List(Of FileInfo)

    For Each ext In extList
        'Returns only the filenames based on the directory that is selected
        Dim fi = From f In New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).GetFiles(ext).Cast(Of IO.FileInfo)() Order By f.CreationTime Select f
        fileList.AddRange(fi)
    Next

    For Each fileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo In fileList
        ListBoxFileAvailable.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it work fine. Below code for list out *.jpg and *.png (Vb.net 2015)

```
    'If option strict off ... use these   
    Dim xtn As Array = {"*.jpg", "*.png"}
    For i = 0 To 1
        For Each foundfile As String In Directory.GetFiles("d:\pic", xtn(i))
            ListBox1.Items.Add(foundfile)
        Next
    Next


   'If option strict on ... use below intead
        Dim xtn(0 To 2) As String
        xtn(0) = "*.jpg"
        xtn(1) = "*.png"
        xtn(2) = "*.jpeg"
        For i = 0 To 2
            For Each foundfile As String In Directory.GetFiles(fld, xtn(i))
                ListBox5.Items.Add(foundfile)
            Next
        Next
```